# Why does Angular 8 recommend Node 12?

Tags: node.js, angular8

Updating from Angular 7.2 to 8.0 the guide at https://update.angular.io/ says to "make sure you are using Node 12 or later". Why does Angular 8 need Node 12 (current)? What could break if I continue using Node 10 (LTS)?

Comment: Why would you want to continue using Node 10 anyway? Node versions are backwards compatible

Comment: At the moment there are issues with Angular and Node 12 (e.g. [this one](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14604)). Besides, I think that an LTS version should also be supported by frameworks. Even the [node.js releases page](https://nodejs.org/en/about/releases/) writes: "Production applications should only use Active LTS or Maintenance LTS releases."

Comment: We do not use Angular 8 for that reason: it relies on a non LTS version of node 12, which is unacceptable to us in production. But Angular 8 is really just a step release prepping for Angular 9 ; so we passed on Angular 8 and will upgrade from Angular 7 directly to Angular 9 which will be released when node 12 LTS will too (October 2019).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe that was a mistake they fixed: https://update.angular.io/

Nothing in there about Node 12 which would be a monstrosity of a disruption for companies that would then need to upgrade all of their build servers with Node 12 before thinking about creating an Angular 8 project.  Happily, that's not true, you can use Node 10 or even Node 8.

Comment: Node 10 or higher is required for the upgrade.

Answer (score 2):

Angular 8 is the current stable release, so it also recommends Node.js latest stable release (i.e. Node.js 12.x.x).

Angular 7 is the current LTS release, so it supports Node.js latest LTS release (i.e. Node.js 10.x.x).

If you want to keep using an LTS release of Node.js (and you may have many reasons for that), you also need an LTS release of Angular (version 7 in this case).

If you think about it, using Angular 8 non-LTS with Node.js LTS would break the main purpose of an LTS software (i.e. stability).

SOURCE: [Angular Release Schedule](https://angular.io/guide/releases#support-policy-and-schedule)

P.S.: I think you can still use Node.js 10 with Angular 8, but since it is not recommended, it could not function properly (in this case, just update to Node.js 12 or stay with Angular 7).

Comment: I didn't realize that Angular 7 was LTS, so this would be a valid reason for Angular 8 to move to Node 12. I will still wait a bit if someone can also answer what could break, otherwise I will mark this as the accepted answer.

Comment: If you want an advice, since [Angular official upgrade instructions](https://update.angular.io/#7.0:8.0) say that Node.js 12 or later is **required**, I would not use an older version of Node.js. Because, even if it apparently doesn't break anything, it is for sure not stable for production (using an unsupported version causes unexpected behavior and **you would not receive much help** in case of problems), and it could break something **in the long run**.

Comment: Be careful about just making stuff up Luca.  Node 12 is the current (latest features) release, nothing in their about "stable" which you added yourself.  You're also implying that we need to align LTS versions and Current versions with respect to Angular and Node: says who?

Comment: I never said that Node.js 12.x.x was LTS, I said that is the latest stable release (i.e. stable means that is not alpha, beta, development etc.); in fact, I specified that Node.js 10.x.x was the latest LTS.
@RickO'Shea Angular itself suggests the correct version of Node.js to use: Angular 8 requires Node.js 12, while Angular 7 requires Node.js 10. The fact that Angular LTS requires Node.js LTS is just an objective observation (and I explained the reason why it makes sense).

Comment: @LucaPolito Each angular version is active for 6 months then goes to LTS for a year. Whereas node releases an LTS each pair version.