# How update node 12 to 16 version in angular project

Tags: node.js, angular, upgrade

Many errors I get when I try to use new version node (16.16.0). My old node version is 12.
How to transition seamlessly?

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
...
}
```

Comment: upgrade angular too, errors will reduce! [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56559152/why-does-angular-8-recommend-node-12)

Comment: To what minimum version of angular can I upgrade to support the 16 version of the node?

Comment: angular 12+ refer [here](https://www.redcricket.net/en/news-en/compatibility-list-for-angular-angular-cli-and-node-js/)

Answer (score 2):

This error appears because you have node 16.X or newer. Npm is stricter than before. Solution 1: downgrade your node version

Solution 2: fix those erros by upgrading all librairies
see: [How to resolve Angular update issue Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/compiler-cli@13.3.11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73218291/how-to-resolve-angular-update-issue-conflicting-peer-dependency-angular-compil/73219658?noredirect=1#comment129314398_73219658)